# Tagging questions about flight footage or video documentation

Tags: discussion, tags

Are there specific tags that can / should be used with questions about footage (for example of a rocket in mid air)?

When I searched the keyword footage (https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=footage), there were mostly questions without such a tag.

The [camera](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camera) tag is often inappropriate as it refers to the devices taking footage rather than video footage itself. The [imaging](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imaging) tag seems to be much about images and sensory devices capturing those, and [photography](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photography) also seems to be inappropriate for video footage questions.

Is there a specific tag I can use, should I just tag it using one of the above (which I consider kind of misleading) or should I just leave out the fact that the question is about footage when tagging it?

Comment: Would it include still images too?  My problem with "footage" is that it is ancient media specific (plus it's based on an obsolete-almost-everywhere-except-USA measurement system).  Would audio/video be more appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

We have a [video](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video) tag. Would that work?